# How to switch off the endpoints of Azure Virtual Machines(VMs) by default, not deletion afterwards?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

How to configure endpoints of Azure VMs, having them shut down by default, when or before I creating VMs?

In another word, how to create Azure VMs without any endpoints assignment?

Removal after VMs creation does not count as the solution for this question.

Answer (score 1):

When using PowerShell / CLI to create ASM VMs you need to explicitly declare the endpoints. See, for example, [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-windows-classic-create-powershell/).

ARM doesn't have the concept of endpoints. If you do not declare a Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses resource and attach it to a NIC (and that to the VM) then the VM won't be on the public internet for inbound traffic.